# $\{(U,\phi),(V,\psi),(V,\gamma)\}$ defines a smooth manifold structure on $U \cup V$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $U = \{(s,0) | s\in \Bbb R\}$, $V = \{(s,0)| s <0\} \cup \{(s,1)|s>0\}$ and $$\phi: U \to \Bbb R, \psi: V \to \Bbb R, \gamma: V \to \Bbb R$$ be respectively given by $$\phi(s,0) = s,\psi(s,0) = s,\psi(s,1) = s , \text{and} \ 
  \gamma(s,0) = s^3,\gamma(s,1) = s^3.$$
To show that $\{(U,\phi),(V,\psi),(V,\gamma)\}$ defines a smooth manifold structure on $U \cup V$.

How to proceed with the problem? Thank You.

Comment: You have to check the maps are compatible with each other. Meaning you have to check the transition map is smooth. There should be other things to check, but the one I pointed out is the main one.

Comment: @Nameless can you tell what else I have to check? I will do the problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

We need to show the compatibility, which means that for all pairs of charts $(A,f)$ and $(B,g)$ we have $f\circ g^{-1}:g(A\cap B)\rightarrow f(A\cap B)$ is smooth, in addition to the requirement that charts must cover our manifold.

Let's show that $(V,\psi)$ and $(V,\gamma)$ are compatible. Your map $\psi \circ \gamma ^{-1}=s^{\frac13}:\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is clearly smooth. Similarly, $(V,\gamma)$ and $(V,\psi)$, because $s^3$ is smooth.

Can you proceed for the remaining maps, namely $\phi\circ\gamma^{-1}$, $\phi\circ\psi^{-1}$, and their inverses $\gamma\circ\phi^{-1}$, $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ ?

Btw, be careful about the domains of your maps. For some cases we are lucky that $V$ doesn't contain $0$.